# Project role base access not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

1. I have setup Jenkins and assign Role-Based Strategy in Authorization

[image]

2. I have created User: developer

I have created global role >> read-access with read privileges and assign read-all-access to developer user

3. I have created two Jenkins Job with below name

   I.  sandbox-pscore-deployment
   II. sandbox-payments-deployment
   III. prod-test
4. I want to give access to developer user on "sandbox-pscore-deployment and sandbox-payments-deployment " job only. Hence I have created Project Role : dev-access and provide pattern "sandbox*" and assign Job privileges >> build | read | workspace |

[image: dev-access role created for developer]

[image: Role Assign to User]
5. Then I have assign role dev-access to User: developer >> Still build privileges not assigned to developer

[image]

Comment: Please try after replacing `sandbox*` with `sandbox.*`.

Comment: Thanks @DibakarAditya It's worked. :)